# Unit test angular with ngrx store and skip

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a function which return an observable. The function implementation look like this.

```
testFunction(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.store.select(testSelector).pipe(
         skip(1),
         take(1),
         map(/*function returning boolean */)
)}
```

how can i unit test this method in angular

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have the following method:

```
testFunction(): Observable<number> { 
  return this.store.pipe(select('count')).pipe( skip(1), take(1) ) 
}
```

you can test it with:

```
  let store: MockStore<{ count: number}>;
  const initialState = { count: 0 };

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     ...
      providers:[
        provideMockStore({ initialState }),
      ]
    ...

    store = TestBed.get<Store>(Store);
  });

...

  it('Test of "skip" pipe without change', fakeAsync(() => {
    let result = 50;
    testFunction().subscribe(_result => result = _result);
    tick();
    expect(result).toBe(50);
  }));

  it('Test of "skip" pipe with new change', fakeAsync(() => {
    let result = 50;
    testFunction().subscribe(_result => result = _result);
    store.setState({ count: 2 });
    tick();
    expect(result).toBe(2);
  }));
```